# Android recyclerview drag and drop to folder or new recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Стоит задача в том что бы реализовать в recyclerview папки и список. Каждый элемент списка, должен иметь возможность перетаскиваться в папку. 
  Можно ли это реализовать в одном recyclerview или например использовать 2 recyclerview? Если два то как перетащить из одного recyclerview во второй.

Answer (score 0):

Вот отличный пример, как использовать [Drag-and-Drop](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.sy818hunm) с помощью  ItemTouchHelper. Да как хотите так и используйте, все зависит от того сколько сил вы готовы вложить. Главное - продумайте логику и способ отображения элементов. Если один RecycleView, то вся логика будет внутри одного адаптера(читай, как отображаются элементы). Ежели два RecycleView - то тут сложнее, через интерфейс ItemTouchHelper придется еще обновлять и два адаптера.